# how to control text color in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, styles, cell

When I run my App first I fill my `datagridview`, then I loop over my rows and change the font color, everything works fine but when I sort my rows (clicking on the head of `datagridview` column) the font color is back to it's origin color.
After checking this subject I found about the attribute 'Default Cell Styles' - I need to know how to disable it on a specific column, I need my font color not to change.

Comment: write your styles in CurrentCellChanged event as well and it will be fine =)

Comment: write it as an answer and I'll approve it :)

Comment: surething =D check out the answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CurrentCellChange Event allows you to provide new action once your `datagridview`'s cell has changed, so basically:

```
private void DataGrid1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //your style code

}
```